# Why do I get a 404?

Tags: python, jquery, django, http-status-code-404, feed

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html but for some reason when I try to load the page I get

`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'static'.` `Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

```
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 141448``
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 167
 "GET /static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1690
 "GET /static/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1702
 "GET /static/js/infinite.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1678
 "GET /static/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1702
 "GET /static/js/infinite.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1678
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="infinite-container">
    {% for number in numbers %}
      <div class="infinite-item">{{ number }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  {% if numbers.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ numbers.next_page_number }}">More</a>
  {% endif %}

  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def home(request):
    numbers_list = range(1, 1000)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(numbers_list, 20)
    try:
        numbers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        numbers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        numbers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'numbers': numbers})
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jquery',
    'feedApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I also installed jQuery by "pip install django-jquery" and also Waypoints by "npm install waypoints"

Comment: you should load `{% load static from staticfiles %}` in each template file where you use the tag `static`.

Comment: The template you have shown wouldn't give that error, because you load the static tag before you use it. The error must be occurring in a different template that you haven't shown. As an aside, `{% load static from staticfiles %}` is deprecated - just use `{% load static %}`.

Comment: We can't really help with the 404s because you haven't said where the static files are located in your project, or what your [static files settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) are.

Comment: @Alasdair i didnt change the static file settings: 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and I also have no other template

Comment: Please have a look through the docs I linked to - there's more to it than simply setting `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

Comment: @Alasdair is it possible that i did something wrong with the installation of jquery or waypoints? cause i dont even have a static folder with the js (at least i dont know where)

Comment: [Part 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial06/) of the tutorial takes you through setting up static files. I would download the js files manually (follow the links in your tutorial), rather than using `npm` or `django-jquery` to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the jquery file in the static/js directory.

Comment: where can I find the file?

Comment: Create a directory static/js in your root directory and put in the code in there. For jquery you would create a file called jquery-3.1.1.min.js in 'static/js' and put in the code in this [link](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js). you need to do it for the other two as well.